# PowerShell v3 installing error

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7

I would like to update my PowerShell from v2 to v3 but when installing, I get a message **"Update not applicable to your computer"**. I tried to install the Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64 Windows Management Framework 3.0 - RC because I am practicing scripting but I can not use the scripts that I am learning in v2.

I do not have a virtual machine.

What is the problem?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64 is applicable to computers running Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Comment: Are you in a non English version operative system?

Comment: My specific is this: 
http://www.kepfeltolto.com/kep/info-2

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you meet the system requirement of .net 4.0

> Windows Management Framework 3.0 requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0"

Comment: It has to be the full install, the client profile isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

The full release of PowerShell and the Windows Management Framework 3.0 has been released, I would suggest using it instead of the release candidate version you mentioned. You can find download links here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=251995

The supported systems matrix is tighter than previous releases - you have to be running one of the following operating systems with the correct service pack level as well:

- Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (32-bit & 64-bit)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (64-bit only, includes Server Core)
- Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2 (32-bit & 64-bit)

Also note, if you have any of the pre-release builds of v3 installed, you will have to remove them before installing the officially released version.